# Run command with files without typing su (error: Permission denied)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, termux

Is it possible to run a command which needs files access but without typing *su*?
I use Termux on Android phone and I would like to create one-line command which I can only paste and run.
For example I tried *sudo su* or *sudo* but I still get "Permission denied" error. But when I write *su* and in next line I enter my command, this works perfect.

My code:

```
$ sudo strings '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0' | grep -oh "http.*$" > '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt'
bash: /data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt: Permission denied


$ su strings '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0' | grep -oh "http.*$" > '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt'
bash: /data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt: Permission denied


$ strings '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0' | grep -oh "http.*$" > '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt'
bash: /data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt: Permission denied
strings: Warning: could not locate '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0'.  reason: Permission denied


$ su
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # strings '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0' | grep -oh "http.*$" > '/data/media/0/!Temp/c/tab_state0NEW.txt'
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home #
```